# MessageBox help

Tags: .net, messagebox

How do I display a MessageBox with Yes and No buttons?

Comment: Which syntax? c#,vb.net,vc++.

Comment: We also need to know the platform. MFC/WinForms/WPF?

Comment: Someone with 13.3K should be know better, and ask questions that are more consise, hence the downvote -ve(1)

Comment: @Darknight this question was not asked by someone with 13.3K...

Comment: Someone with 200 should know better and know questioner from the editor;-)

Comment: d'oh sorry, I'm hungry my concentraction is low...

Comment: argh, God, apologies, I'm making spelling and grammatical errors all over the place...

Answer (score 10):

```
MessageBox.Show("text", "caption", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
```

.NET / C#

Answer (score 4):

```
if (confirm("Did you want to know how to do it in Javascript?"))
{
    alert("You did? Great!");
}
else
{
    alert("No? Tag your question with the required language/environment!");
}
```

Or alternatively,

```
int result = MessageBox(
        NULL,
        (LPCWSTR)L"So, did you want a Win32 example?",
        (LPCWSTR)L"OK, the javascript one was flawed",
        MB_ICONQUESTION | MB_YESNO
    );
```

or maybe

```
 int result = AfxMessageBox("Do people still use MFC?", 
     MB_ICONQUESTION | MB_YESNO);
```

Comment: Except for that would be "Ok", "Cancel" ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
if( MessageBox.Show("Are you sure?", "MessageTitle", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes )
   MessageBox.Show("You clicked Yes.");
else
   MessageBox.Show("You clicked No.");
```

Comment: For what I can tell by using the same function name all three message boxen have the "yes" and "no" buttons? ;-)

Comment: Erm, I think you're missing a method parameter.

Comment: Should have included the MessageBoxButtons parameter: MessageBox.Show("Are you sure?", "MessageTitle", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo )

Comment: If I were the one who downrated the answer I'd revoke my vote after it's been fixed :-)

Comment: It's still not clear, though, what platform the question applies to:)

Comment: -1 because this looks like C# and default messagebox.show shows only an ok button.

Comment: i edited my answer because i accidently pressed Ctrl+Enter and it submitted my answer before it was complete